# How to append a parent to a messagebox showinfo in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to foucs the self.root after messagebox,but this gives me an error because it takes only 2 Arguments how can I append a parent to it ?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
...
messagebox.showinfo(parent=self.root,"Delete Item", "Item Deleted successfully ! ")
```

The error :

> ```
> messagebox.showinfo('self.root',"Delete Item", "Item Deleted successfully ! ")
> ```
>
> TypeError: showinfo() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: I am useing :    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

Comment: I have added the tag. For future questions, please be sure to add the library. There are plenty of toolboxes for creating GUIs, we don't necessarily know which you are referring to

Comment: from tkinter import * from tkinter import ttk from tkinter import messagebox

Comment: The code you have posted does not produce the error you get. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)